# What is the difference between a parameterized class and a metaclass (code examples in Python please)?

Tags: python, class, metaclass, parameterized

Hello Stack Overflow contributers,

I'm a novice programmer learning Python right now, and I came upon [this site](http://www.ipipan.gda.pl/~marek/objects/TOA/oobasics/oobasics.html) which helps explain object-oriented paradigms. I know that metaclasses are classes of classes (like how meta-directories are directories of directories, etc. etc.), but I'm having trouble with something: What is the actual difference between a metaclass and a parameterized class, according to the website's definition?

If you can, please include code examples in Python that illustrate the differences between the two. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [this site](http://www.ipipan.gda.pl/~marek/objects/TOA/oobasics/oobasics.html) does not exists any more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python doesn't have (or need) "parameterized classes", so it's hard to provide examples of them in Python;-).  A metaclass is simply "the class of a class": normally `type` (as long, in Py2, as you remember to make the class new-style by inheriting from `object`, or some other built-in type or other new-style class -- old-style classes are a legacy artefact in Py2, fortunately disappeared in Py3, and you should ideally just forget about them).  You can make a custom metaclass (usually subclassing `type`) for several advanced purposes, but it's unlikely that you'll ever *need* to (esp. considering that, since python 2.6, much of what used to require a custom metaclass can now be done more simply with a class decorator).

Given any class C, `type(C)` is its metaclass.

A parameterized class is a completely different concept.  Closest you can come to it in Python is probably a factory function that makes and returns a class based on its arguments:

```
def silly(n):
    class Silly(object):
        buh = ' '.join(n * ['hello'])
    return Silly

Silly1 = silly(1)
Silly2 = silly(2)
a = Silly1()
print(a.buh)
b = Silly2()
print(b.buh)
```

will print

```
hello
hello hello
```

Again, it's definitely **not** something you'll need often — making several classes that differ just by one or a few arguments.  Anyway, as you can see, it has absolutely nothing to do with the classes' class (AKA metaclass), which is always `type` in this example (and in almost every more realistic example I could think of — I just chose to give a simple example, where the point of doing this is hard to discern, rather than a realistic and therefore necessarily very complex one ;-).

Comment: I switched to Py3 a couple of days ago, thinking that since I'm just a student right now, I should learn the 'hip new thing' of tomorrow. Guess that was a smart move :-)

Answer (score 0):

This [write up](http://www.acooke.org/cute/PythonMeta0.html) may be of help. And [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpdecor.html) is an oldie but worth a read as well. I know that this doesn't fully answer your question but I hope it gives you food for thought.